# Network info in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

In every other browser I simply select 'network' in the development tools area to see files used on a website (to see download times etc.)

I can't see any way to do this in Firefox.

I've downloaded Fiddler, Tamper and Live HTTP Headers plugins, but I just simply want to view the files being used on a website, but can't see how.

Is that even possible with Firefox?

Comment: Shouldn't Firebug give you that information? If not, please clarify why not.

Comment: Yes it does, shouldn't this be an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Get Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/). Mozilla *plans to improve* their DevTools with an Network Panel & More soon. These are tools you'll find in [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) and [firebug](/questions/tagged/firebug), **but not** in the Firefox DevTools yet. [Victor Porof](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Team) is working on this, and he managed to get a working [prototype](http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=f-jVZDKV90I).

[image]

Comment: Yes, but Firebug freezes the whole browser regularly, and in some cases keeps pages from loading. The answer below should work in those instances.

Comment: @NoBugs well, every stack overflow in the console output "freezes" a browser, nothing new and not [tag:firebug] related. You don't know the key benefits of [tag:firebug]...

Comment: I have used Firebug for years, and on recent versions of Firefox it has sometimes frozen the whole browser for no apparent reason. It's not just me noticing this problem, which is unfortunate - Firebug used to be the best debugger ever.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that even possible with Firefox?

The answer is, "Yes".

Press `CTRL+SHIFT+K` to open `Web Console` in Firefox.

Then select the `Net`work tab to see the list of files along with their *download times*.

[image: Web Console]

**EDIT**:
XHR requests being captured in the `Net`work tab.

[image: XHR requedts]

Comment: why was this downvoted - this is the answer, until they add Network panel to Firefox.

Comment: @NoBugs Apparently, some people know far more about Firebug than their browsers. Check screen shot of XHR requests being captured.

Comment: I remember getting AJAX records on the console, maybe it was added recently.